# How to trim cell values in an attribute field

Tags: arcmap, field-calculator, attribute-table

I am working in ArcMap 10.4.1 and need to trim cell values in the NAME field of a feature class. Everything starting from double underscores needs to be deleted. This is my attempt in Field Calculator... [Name]LTrim("__"). This results in the Field Calculator telling me

> "There was a failure during processing, check the Geoprocessing Results window for details."

the Geoprocessing Results window says,

> "General error executing calculator", "ERROR 999999: Error executing function", "Type mismatch: 'esri__1LTrim'", "Failed to execute (CalculateField)"

The field is a String and I get the same error message regardless of whether I put the underscores in double quotes, single quotes or no quotes. But if I use no quotes, it says "Invalid character" instead of "Type mismatch..." in the Results.

Comment: Did you check the Geoprocessing Results window for details? What did it say?

Comment: I would paste the screenshot, but I don't think that's possible in a comment... It says, "General error executing calculator", "ERROR 999999: Error executing function", "Type mismatch: 'esri__1LTrim'", "Failed to execute (CalculateField)"

Comment: The field is a String and I get the same error message regardless of whether I put the underscores in double quotes, single quotes or no quotes. But if I use no quotes, it says "Invalid character" instead of "Type mismatch..." in the Results.

Comment: That's what the [edit] link under the post is for. But error messages should always be provided as text (which is searchable), not as an image.

Comment: Wrong syntax for ltrim([field]) and it removes spaces only. Try python !field!.lstrip("_")

Comment: [Note: the double underscores in the following code are not showing up in this post.] I have tried !Name!.lstrip("__"), !Name!.rstrip("__") and !Name!.strip("__") and it executes without error, but nothing happens. I add the output feature class to the TOC and see in the attribute table that no edits were made to the cells in the field. So nothing happened to Name in the original feature class, as well as in the output feature class. Just to clarify what I am trying to trim... If a cell in the Name field has as its value, "Ch Homer East__13.7mi" I need __13.7mi to be deleted.

Comment: `strip()` deals with characters at either end of the string, and with that knowledge I bet you can guess what `lstrip()` and `rstrip()` do.  Try `!Name!.replace('_', '')` instead to remove the underscores, or `!Name!.split('_')[0]` to handle the case you've outlined in your comment.

Comment: !Name!.split('__')[0] worked, so that is the answer. Thank you..